# ZoomTo in Anychart Network Graph

Tags: javascript, anychart

How can i zoom to a node in a graph network anychart ?

It seems that the zoomTo function is not accessible for this kind of graph.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible zooming to the direct node in the graph chart. 
However, you can zoom graph charts by mouse wheel scroll.

You can find more information on [documentation page about the zoomOnMouseWheel](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.graph.elements.Interactivity#zoomOnMouseWheel) method. 
Also, please explore the [playground demo of the zoomOnMouseWheel](https://playground.anychart.com/api/core/graph/elements/_samples/anychart.core.graph.elements.Interactivity.zoomAndScroll_set) method.